# table formatting dilemma

Tags: html

[image]

i always manage to stuff up tables. i want to make one like the top image but im getting the bottom image with:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</td>
<td rowspan="3"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

can someone please correct my work. i know its lazy but ive already tried like 6 combinations and cant get the right one and its becoming very frustrating. is there some kind of free tool available to format tables to prevent me having this issue in future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="80" rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <!--<td>&nbsp;</td>-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <!--<td>&nbsp;</td>-->
    </tr>
</table>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xXD3T/)

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid HTML. You cannot have `<tr>` as children of `<td>`.

Try this instead...

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```